# How to change Global Variable value in python other than the function in which it is declared?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

How can I change Global Variable value in python other than the function in which it is declared?
i.e. it is declared in function f21 but i want to set its value again when function f22() will be called.
I am using Python 3.6.

```
def f21():
 global x
 x=21
 print('value of global variable x in f21 was: ',x)

def f22():
 x=22 # Set global variable value again
 print('value of global variable after changing in function f22 is: ',x)

def f23():
 print('Current value of global variable should be 22 as set in function f22 but it is: ',x)

f21()
f22()
f23()
```

Comment: ... I feel that you already knew the answer (use the `global x` statement). I have no idea where you're stuck at.

Comment: You mean like this ?  global x=22

Comment: The same way as you done it in `f21()`.

Comment: I am getting invalid syntax error if i add global before x in function f22()

Comment: Ohh , I got it now

Comment: So we need to declare it global everytime we want to change the value ?

Comment: Yes. On the other hand you could write your program in a different way so that you don't need `global`. Using `global` is almost always bad style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the global statement in any function where you're setting the value, including in this case `f22()`.

Comment: I am getting syntax error if using global x=22 in f22()